# Corrupted ZIP file from Resteasy download

Tags: java, rest, http, resteasy

Problem is, after the download of a zip file from a REST service I've got something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Report_request_2681.zip
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 1843
Date: Tue, 24 May 2016 15:24:39 GMT

PK etc etc... my real zip file bytes
```

The zip file generated is correct (tried directly copying it from the server, the size is 1843 bytes), the fault lies in the download method (resteasy add the HTTP header to the file, so the final size is 1843 bytes + header part). Here is my `resteasy` implementation (I've removed non influential parts):

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Path("/download/{fileName}")
Response getRequestedFile(
        @Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
        @PathParam("fileName") String fileName
);

    //... bla bla bla method and authentication stuff

    //Prepare a file object with file to return
    File file = new File(myPath);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }

    try {
        return Response.ok(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE).header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + cleanFileName + "\"").build();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
```

I'm using `resteasy 2.1.0 GA` (and I cannot upgrade it). The method `readFileToByteArray` is taken from `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`. I've tried setting the content to text/plain or application/zip and passing a FileInputStream to the Response, but the problem still persist. Any tips?

Oh, I've also tried download via REST method with a simple text file... same problem, at the start of the downloaded file I've got the HTTP response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Report_request_2681"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 16550
Date: Wed, 25 May 2016 07:03:20 GMT

...rest of my txt file
```

edit: integrated comment infos in the question.

Comment: You say you're getting "my real zip file bytes" - so what's the difference between those bytes and the original zip file? Are they they same length?

Comment: The Content-Length agrees with the file size? Using application/octet-stream is fine. The bytes begin okay (PK...), Maybe the manual upload and download use FTP in textual mode instead of binary mode, which convert between `\n` and `\r\n`. Try other files.

Comment: The file (without the header part is 1843 bytes). I've checked it by taking it directly from the server, without downloading via REST service. That part is added by resteasy without doubt.

Comment: Just to be clear, if I open the downloaded file it got the HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Report_request_2681.zip
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 1843
Date: Tue, 24 May 2016 15:24:39 GMT part, without downloading it via ws it only has the PK... part (which is the correct zip file)

Comment: What does `FileUtils.readFileToByteArray` do; if this is your own code: show it, if it is standard code: which library?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It's org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils... but I've also tried passing directly  the file (like Response.ok((Object)file).header...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No simple solution was found for this issue, as a workaround I've created a servlet to download the file (from the new URL, the zipped file wasn't corrupted), so I've changed my `resteasy` implementation to do a redirect:

```
....
String redirectPath = StringUtils.substringBefore(httpRequest.getRequestURL().toString(), "restws") + "download?fileName=" + fileName + "&actionId=" + actionRequestId + "&check=" + encodedString;
return Response.seeOther(URI.create(redirectPath)).build();
```

where the `check` parameter is simple encoded token, containing a timestamp, used for simmetric security. It avoided me the full port of authentication/role logic in the servlet (if the servlet URL isn't called in less than 3 seconds from the REST method, the request will return a 400). 
Not an elegant solution, but at least now the file is no longer corrupted.

P.S. By the way, just as a note: `WinRAR` will handle the corrupted file just fine (also `7zip` version 9.2), `Windows Explorer` and the last version of `7zip` cannot open it.